# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape () for Tensor 'input_example_tensor:0', which has shape '(?,)'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-serving

Why this error appear?

I cannot find similar to mine case with an answer with an explanation why that's happening. There are a lot of info there for such errors, but seems like it depends on a lot of reasons and for different cases, it can have different solutions.

So I am trying to load `TensorFlow` trained model, then convert it into `TensorFlow Serving` model format and that makes a prediction.

[iris_data.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/samples/core/get_started/iris_data.py) file from import bellow.

That's how I export my model (train already did, I just load it from disk):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import iris_data
from tensorflow.contrib import predictor

# Fetch the data
    (train_x, train_y), (test_x, test_y) = iris_data.load_data()

    # Feature columns describe how to use the input.
    my_feature_columns = []
    for key in train_x.keys():
        my_feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key=key))

    # Build 2 hidden layer DNN with 10, 10 units respectively.
    classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
        feature_columns=my_feature_columns,
        # Two hidden layers of 10 nodes each.
        hidden_units=[10, 10],
        # The model must choose between 3 classes.
        n_classes=3,
        model_dir='G:\AI models')

    #converting into TensorFlow Serving model format 
    path = 'G:\AI models\serve'
    feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(my_feature_columns)
    export_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)
    servable_model_path = classifier.export_savedmodel(path, export_input_fn, as_text=True)
```

Here is how I try to get a prediction using `TensorFlow Serving` model:

```
 expected = ['Setosa', 'Versicolor', 'Virginica']
    predict_x = {
        'SepalLength': [5.1, 5.9, 6.9],
        'SepalWidth': [3.3, 3.0, 3.1],
        'PetalLength': [1.7, 4.2, 5.4],
        'PetalWidth': [0.5, 1.5, 2.1],
    }
path = 'G:\AI models\serve\\1519413839'
    predict_fn = predictor.from_saved_model(path)
    predictions = predict_fn(
        {"inputs": predict_x})
```

And finally get an error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape () for Tensor 'input_example_tensor:0', which has shape '(?,)'
```

Comment: What line does it fail on?

Comment: @Yserbius  predictions = predict_fn(
        {"inputs": predict_x})

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass your sample using Example API:

```
feature = {
    'SepalLength': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[5.1])),
    'SepalWidth': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[3.3])),
    'PetalLength': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[1.7])),
    'PetalWidth': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[0.5]))
}
example = tf.train.Example(
    features=tf.train.Features(
        feature=feature
    )
)
serialized_example = example.SerializeToString()

predictions = predict_fn({"inputs": [serialized_example]})
```

You can pass many examples if you want, of course.

Useful link: http://shzhangji.com/blog/2018/05/14/serve-tensorflow-estimator-with-savedmodel/

Answer (score 0):

`()` are the dimensions of a zero rank tensor (ie. a scalar), and `(?,)` is a rank one tensor (vector) of unknown dimension.

Without the complete stack trace that's all I'm able to tell you.

Comment: What can I share for you to help you ? Probably I didn't convert model by the correct way...

Comment: Stack trace are the lines printed above the error, it shoud start in your code, and end somewere in tensorflow.

Answer (score -1):

```
'G:\AI models\serve\\1519413839'
```

should be

```
'G:\\AI models\\serve\\1519413839'
```

Backslashes need to be escaped. It's possible that the file isn't being read making the predictor function have a zero-dimension tensor shape as its data.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't helped me :(